# Meta Programming, whats it good for?

Tags: metaprogramming

So Meta Programming -- the idea that you can modify classes/objects at runtime, injecting new methods and properties.  I know its good for framework development; been working with Grails, and that framework adds a bunch of methods to your classes at runtime.  You have a name property on a User object, and bamm, you get a findByName method injected at runtime.

1. Has my description completely described the concept?
2. What else is it good for (specific examples) other than framework development?

Comment: What is it good for? Absolutely nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(Edwin_Starr_song)

Comment: As a few answers have pointed out, your description is not correct. Your description seems to refer to reflection, and aspect-oriented programming (AOP). These two extends the language's capability at runtime. Metaprogramming extends the language's capability at compile-time, and in particular the capability of operating on types (in a type system). Reflection, on the other hand, adds the capability of operating on types at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, meta-programming is "a program that writes programs".

Meta-programming is especially good for reuse, because it supports generalization: you can define a *family* of concepts that belong to a particular *pattern*. Then, through *variability* you can apply that concept in similar, but different scenarios.

The simplest example is Java's getters and setters as mentioned by @Sjoerd:

Both getter and setter follow a well-defined *pattern*: A getter returns a class member, and a setter sets a class member's value. Usually you build what it's called a *template* to allow application and reuse of that particular pattern. How a template works depends on the meta-programming/code generation approach being used.

If you want a getter or setter to behave in a slightly different way, you may add some parameters to your template. This is *variability*. For instance, if you want to add additional processing code when getting/setting, you may add a block of code as a variability parameter. Mixing custom code and generated code can be tricky. [ABSE](http://www.abse.info) is currently the only MDSD approach that I know that natively supports custom code directly as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Meta programming is not only adding methods at runtime, it can also be automatically creating code at compile time. I.e. code generating code.

- Web services (i.e. the methods are defined in the WSDL, and you want to use them as if they were real methods on an object)
- Avoiding boilerplate code. For example, in Java you should use getters and setters, but these can be made automatically for most properties.

Comment: i thought metaprogramming was specifically a runtime thing.  Interesting.  Good point about boiler plate code (Grails does this too).  Anything else?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: Metaprogramming is mostly about compile-time; runtime uses are actually pretty rare in comparision to run-time usages. See f.e. C++ templates (which is kind of metaprogramming, even though not many people like to admit that): all programs that use STL... there are lots of them.